# Making a loop with sf::Time

Tags: c++, sfml

Can I make a loop using sf::time class, as when I try and do this my program crashes.

```
while(time.asSeconds() <= 10.0f)
```

This is the while loop I used with sf::Time class.

Comment: Are you missing some code here? What is your code meant to do?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that my code is supposed to be an Astroid game, I'm trying to get the shooting meachanic in the game The rest of the code is. void Bullet::Shoot(){
 sf::Time time;
 sf::Clock clock;
 time = clock.getElapsedTime();
 while(time.asSeconds() <= 10.0f){
  bullet.move(sin(3.14159265*bullet.getRotation()/180)*10 ,cos(3.14159265*bullet.getRotation()/180)*10);
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

```
sf::Clock clock; // Initializing clock starts counting time.
while(someCondition)
{
    sf::Time time = clock.getElapsedTime();
    //It's going to execute do something() until time is higher than 10.0f
    while(time.asSeconds() <= 10.0f)
    {
        //we need this to ensure that we won't fall into the infinite loop
        time = clock.getElapsedTime();
        do something()
        //Optional: clock.restart(); If you want your code to be executed every x seconds.
    }
}
```

First you have to create sf::Clock variable, then grab time from clock to sf::Time variable.